# SCARD_F_INTERNAL_ERROR result from SCardGetStatusChange

Tags: delphi, smartcard, pcsc, winscard

I'm developing application that is using Mifare Classic 1K card and HID Omnikey 5421 (successor of 5321). I using thread to detect card remove/insert.
Delphi code (thread method):

```
function CardWatcherThread(PContext: Pointer): integer;
var
  RetVar   : cardinal;
  RContext : cardinal;
  RStates  : array[0..0] of SCARD_READERSTATEA;
begin
  try
    RContext := Cardinal(PContext^);
    FillChar(RStates,SizeOf(RStates),#0);
    RStates[0].szReader       := SelectedReader;
    RStates[0].pvUserData     := nil;
    RStates[0].dwCurrentState := SCARD_STATE_UNAWARE;
    while ReaderOpen and (not Application.Terminated) do begin
      RetVar := SCardGetStatusChange(RContext, MAX_WAIT_TIME_SCARDSTATUSCHANGE, @RStates, 1);
      RStates[0].dwCurrentState := RStates[0].dwEventState;
      ActReaderState := RStates[0].dwEventState;

      // Avoid sedning error about timemout if MAX_WAIT_TIME_SCARDSTATUSCHANGE is not infinite
      if (RetVar <> SCARD_E_TIMEOUT) or (MAX_WAIT_TIME_SCARDSTATUSCHANGE = -1) then begin
        SendMessage(NotifyHandle, WM_CARDSTATE, RetVar, 0);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Result := 0;
  end;
end;
```

I'm using SendMessage to notify my Smart Card class where I'm detecting proper state. Also I automatically connect and read data from smart card when I detect card insertion.

My application is working correctly for most of the time, but sometimes for e.g. once in the 10000 of card insertion I'm getting **SCARD_F_INTERNAL_ERROR** from `SCardGetStatusChange`. When this happen SCardGetStatusChange is starting to result only **SCARD_F_INTERNAL_ERROR** all the time. When I detected this situation I tried to `SCardCancel` and `SCardReleaseContext`, end thread and establish new context and create new watcher thread with this new context but this is not helping because SCardGetStatusChange was continue to returning **SCARD_F_INTERNAL_ERROR**. Only when I close application and run again problem disappears. 
 It's happening randomly for me, I can't reproduce it using some known scenario. In PC can be more readers, but I'm establishing connection only to Omnikey 5421.

Someone met with this problem?

Comment: I highly doubt that you'll find help here. Contact the vendor of the hardware you use.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tried to contact with HID but with no response :/

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what goes wrong but I have few remarks about your code, hope they help...

- you should check the return value of the `SCardGetStatusChange` as the first thing and if it is `SCARD_E_TIMEOUT` then just skip all the processing and start next cycle;
- instead of just `RStates[0].dwCurrentState := RStates[0].dwEventState;` you also have to clear out the `SCARD_STATE_CHANGED` bit from the state (that is, if the state actually changed);
- it is my understanding that the resource manager context might become invalid, so before calling `SCardGetStatusChange` use [SCardIsValidContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make sure you still have good context, if not acquire new one;

So try something like this (this is typed to the browser, so untestead and probably wont compile as is):

```
function CardWatcherThread(PContext: Pointer): integer;
var
  RetVar   : cardinal;
  RContext : cardinal;
  RStates  : array[0..0] of SCARD_READERSTATEA;
begin
  try
    RContext := Cardinal(PContext^);
    FillChar(RStates,SizeOf(RStates),#0);
    RStates[0].szReader       := SelectedReader;
    RStates[0].pvUserData     := nil;
    RStates[0].dwCurrentState := SCARD_STATE_UNAWARE;
    while ReaderOpen and (not Application.Terminated) do begin
      if(SCardIsValidContext(RContext) <> SCARD_S_SUCCESS)then begin
         RetVal := SCardEstablishContext(...);
      end;
      RetVar := SCardGetStatusChange(RContext, MAX_WAIT_TIME_SCARDSTATUSCHANGE, @RStates, 1);
      case RetVal of
        SCARD_E_TIMEOUT:;
        SCARD_S_SUCCESS: begin
           if((RStates[0].dwEventState and SCARD_STATE_CHANGED) <> 0)then begin
              RStates[0].dwCurrentState := RStates[0].dwEventState xor SCARD_STATE_CHANGED;
              // reader's state changed, do something
           end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Result := 0;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: First thanks for your really good points. I will try this and see if that helps. There is a hope :)